# Custom permission-based view in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010

In either SharePoint 2007 or 2010, I am looking for a way to do a particular type of custom view.  I don't think this is default in the product and would possibly need some scripting.  (hopefully I am wrong).

Let's say I have 3 columns in the list, 2 with data and 1 with the owner (tied to single signed on account).

I want to limit the active user's view of that list to only the rows that have them as the owner.  Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found a great answer to this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/58f62e16-699a-4489-9e74-e5bb8ed8c51c

Comment: belongs on sharepointoverflow

Comment: I have written a blog on it recently, might be useful for someone [Filter SharePoint List Based on Permission](http://sharepointlogics.com/2014/02/how-to-filter-sharepoint-list-based-on.html)

Answer (score 1):

Found a great answer thread for this

[Technet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointgeneral/thread/58f62e16-699a-4489-9e74-e5bb8ed8c51c)

Answer (score 1):

In the view's filter setting set the Owner column to [Me]

Answer (score 0):

Be aware, though, that this just filters out the items from the view you are modifying. Users who are smart enough to open RSS view of that list, open the list in Excel or Ms Access will still see the "hidden" items.